# Differenze di uso tra "cambiamento" e "cambio" nel senso di "mutamento" o "trasformazione"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, nouns

Ho letto il contenuto delle voci [*cambio*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cambio) e [*cambiamento*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cambiamento), ma non mi è per niente chiaro se ci siano differenze di uso tra questi termini quando sono utilizzati con il significato di "mutamento" o "trasformazione".

Per esempio, nel libro *Introduzione alla linguistica romanza* di Charmaine Lee e Sabrina Galano ho letto la frase

> L'espansionismo di Roma ha potuto  accelerare il cambio della lingua in due modi

ma poi mi è sembrato di capire che si parla di [*cambiamento linguistico*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambiamento_linguistico).

Potrei anche dire "L'espansionismo di Roma ha potuto accelerare il cambiamento della lingua in due modi"?

Comment: Dovresti, secondo me: *cambiamento* è l'azione del cambiare; *cambio* è già avvenuto.

Comment: @egreg: Vuoi dire che dovrei sostituire "cambio" con "cambiamento" nella frase citata?

Comment: Sì, mi riferivo all'ultimo capoverso, che comincia con “potrei”.

Comment: Nella frase proposta cambiamento e forse più “corretto” di cambio. Cambiamento si riferisce ad una trasformazione, tipico dell’evoluzione lenta e graduale delle lingue. Cambio si usa più spesso riferito allo scambio di una cosa per un’altra come tra l’altro suggerito nei dizionari.

Comment: Un “cambio di stagione” si riferisce all’avvicendarsi   di una stagione con la successiva (inverno con la primavera ad esempio). Un cambiamento di stagione suggerisce che una stagione, ad esempio l’inverno, non è più gelido com’era in passato ma più mite, come  una primavera in anticipo.

Answer (score 2):

Con *cambio* ci si riferisce ad una sostituzione, cioè qualcosa che prima era presente è stato sostituito da qualcos'altro. La frase originale che hai citato presuppone che Roma abbia sostituito un linguaggio con un altro (per esempio dal germanico al latino). Mentre il sostantivo *cambiamento* indica una trasformazione, cioè qualcosa che muta senza la necessità di una sostituzione. Perciò *cambiamento della lingua*  mi sembra adatto ad intendere che il linguaggio sia mutato nella forma (evoluto) ma non per forza sostituito da uno nuovo. Inoltre *cambiamento* indica un processo più graduale di *cambio*. Nella maggioranza dei casi questi due termini sono pressoché intercambiabili, però nel tuo caso il significato della frase sembra variare.